# Keeping exact wave form in memory

Tags: math, trigonometry

Let's say I have a program that calculates the value of the sine wave at time `t`. The sine wave is of the form `sin(f*t + phi)`. Amplitude is `1`.

If I only have one `sin` term all is fine. I can easily calculate the value at any time `t`.

But, at runtime, the wave form becomes modified when it combines with other waves. `sin(f1 * t + phi1) + sin(f2 * t + phi2) + sin(f3 * t + phi3) + ...`

The simplest solution is to have a table with columns for `phi` and `f`, iterate over all rows, and sum the results. But to me it feels that once I reach thousands of rows, the computation will become slow.

Is there a different way of doing this? Like combining all the sines into one statement/formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Fourier series (i.e. `f_i` = `i f` for some f) you can use the [Clenshaw recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw_algorithm) which is significantly faster than computing all the sines (but it might be slightly less accurate).

---

In your case you can consider the sequence:

```
f_k = exp( i ( k f t + phi_k) ) , where i is the imaginary unit.
```

Notice that `Im(f_k)` = `sin( k f t + phi_k )`, that is your sequence.

Also

```
f_k = exp( i ( k f t + phi_k) ) = exp( i k f t ) exp( i phi_k )
```

Hence you have `a_k = exp(i phi_k)`. You can precompute these values and store them in an array. For simplicity from now on assume `a_0 = 0`.

Now, `exp( i (k + 1) f t) = exp(i k f t) * exp(i f t)`, so `alpha_k = exp(i f t)` and `beta_k = 0`.

You can now apply the recurrence formula, in C++ you can do something like this:

```
complex<double> clenshaw_fourier(double f, double t, const vector< complex<double> > & a )
{
    const complex<double> alpha = exp(f * t * i);

    complex<double> b = 0;

    for (int k = a.size() - 1; k >0; -- k )
        b = a[k] + alpha * b;

    return a[0] + alpha * b;
}
```

Assuming that `a[k] == exp( i phi_k )`.

The real part of the answer is the sum of `cos(k f t + phi_k)`, while the imaginary part is the sum of `sin(k f t + phi_k)`.

As you can see this only uses addition and multiplications, except for  `exp(f * t * i)` that is only computed once.

Comment: can you expand on your answer? I especially do not understand how I can fulfill this condition http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/e/7/2/e729834a0c5f698207d3ad23ed7b1bf7.png

Answer (score 1):

There are different bases (plural of basis) that can be advantageous (i.e. compact) for representing different waveforms. The most common and well-known one is that which you mention, called the Fourier basis usually. Daubechies wavelets for example are a relatively recent addition that cope with more discontinuous waveforms much better than a Fourier basis does. But this is really a math topic and probably if you post on Math Overflow you will get better answers.

Comment: Are they going to be more or less equally computationally efficient?

Comment: If your functions are smooth and sinusoidal, Fourier basis is best. If you have sharp edges, you want to go for wavelets. Wavelet compression (or approximation if you will) can be blindingly fast. And there are other things out there too.